# Access all images of a div and display the count of images which has undefined or no src

Tags: javascript, image, html, src

I would like to access all the images from a particular div like

```
<div id="mydiv">
 <div id="mydiv1">
  <img  src="pic.jpg">
  <img  src="pic.jpg">
  <img  src="">`enter code here`
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv2">
  <img href="#">
  <img  src="pic.jpg">
  <img  src="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Its a dynamic page what i need to do is to get all images's src from this div and check which image has no image link in its src and according to this display the alert

Im new to java script please help me out.

Comment: <img> tag should not have "href" attribute!

Comment: @tborychowski It didn't originally have them, but an answer here suggested it for some reason, which is why I think the OP edited it in.

Comment: It's becoming unclear to me what you actually want. I thought you wanted an alert for each image without a src, but below you have a comment that makes it sound like you want the count? Could you please clarify?

Comment: first i need to count the image actually its for a dynamic wensite.if count is less than 12 then i need to give an alert

Comment: You should update the question to indicate that. I'll update my answer. -- And you're absolutely certain you want to alert if the number of images without a source is *less than* 12? That just seems kind of strange.

Answer (score 2):

```
var imgs = document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('img');
var countImagesWithoutSrc = 0;

var curImg;
for(var i = 0; i < imgs .length; i++) {
  curImg = imgs[i];

  if(!curImg.src || !curImg.src.length) {
    ++countImagesWithoutSrc;
  }
}

alert(countImagesWithoutSrc); //gives you the number of images missing a src attribute
```

Comment: It's declared in the for loop. Each time through the loop, it contains a reference to one of the entities stored in imgs.

Comment: I'm dumb. I program too much PHP - you can't use this for() syntax for arrays in Javascript :(. I'm updating, just a sec.

Answer (score 1):

```
var images = document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('img');
var emptyimg = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    if(images[i].src=="")
        emptyimg.push(images[i]);
}
```

To quote your comment:

> yes i need to count of blank src images

To find the number of images with empty src attributes:

```
var count = 0
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    if(images[i].src)
        count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what i need to do is to find out the image which has "" src

Comment: The question wants to know which images have no src value. This gets all the src values, but then you lose the information of which image had which src. Just do if(!images[i].src || !images[i].src.length) alert('heyo') in your loop.

Comment: @user1881845 Do you want the number of images with blank `src` attributes, an array of non blank `src` attribute values, or an array of `img` nodes with non blank `src` attributes?

Comment: @user1881845 In that case, just remove the `==""`. Both empty strings and undefined are falsy.

Answer (score 1):

First add jQuery library and write down following code to find out images count.

```
var imageCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div').children('img').each(function(index,item){
       if($(this).attr('src') == "" || $(this).attr('src') == undefined)
       {
           count++;
       }
   });
   alert(count);
});
```

if you are using only javascript then please use below code:-

```
 for(j=0;j < document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;j++)
                {
                    if(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[j].getAttribute('src') == "")
                    {
                        count++
                    }

                }
```

Please check and let me know if this is not working out or if you want something other than this.

Regards
Durgaprasad

Comment: The question does not have a jQuery tag.

Comment: Could you please provide me solution in java script what i need to do is to find out images which has "" src

Comment: Everyone on SO seems to think everything needs to be done with jQuery. Sometimes people want to work with native Javascript.

Comment: i need solution in java script

Comment: AmericanUmlaut he stated that he is new to JavaScript so maybe knowing jQuery would help him a lot. If someone can't use jQuery, he is stating this in question as far as I have seen.

Comment: Please use below code :-
 for(j=0;j < document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;j++)
                {
                    if(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[j].getAttribute('src') == "")
                    {
                        count++
                    }

                }

Answer (score 0):

your html code is not very clear you can't have img with html files as source unless they are jpeg files with html extension

```
<img src="somepage.html">
```

if you want to link them you need and anchor tag 
it's 
`<a href="somepage.html" ><img src="picsrc.jpg"></a>`

maybe it's cause of that

Comment: yes i have edited the code but i need to find out the image count which has "" or undefined src

Answer (score 0):

Get to know jQuery at first where you can use something like this:

```
$('img').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: The question does not have a jQuery tag.

Comment: He stated that he is new to JavaScript has starting score, so maybe he doesn't know about JQuery. ;)